# Badge screen appears all jumbled

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badge-progress

I'm getting a scrambled interface when I go to my profile and click on "Next badge". When I look at either gold, silver or bronze, the badges *initially* appear all jumbled:

[image: Jumbled1]

I figured it was probably just because of my zoom % on my screen, and zooming in/out immediately fixed it:

[image: Jumbled2]

However, it doesn't appear to matter what zoom % I'm at, it's always just whenever I initially open the badge screen to look at them. I can zoom to any percentage after that first zoom, and it's fixed. I looked around on Stack Overflow meta to see if anyone else had encountered this before, but didn't see anything.

This is on internet explorer.

Comment: Have you tried 100% zoom?

Comment: @Stijn Yep, I've tried all percentages. Doesn't matter what it's set to, it always initially starts jumbled, and is quickly fixed once I zoom in or out, by whatever percentage.

Comment: Gratz to MS... someone is using IE... no repro on Chrome latest

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer? We [only support the last two versions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). As of this moment--and probably forever, as IE has been replaced by Edge in Microsoft's view--that would appear to be 11 and 10.

Comment: @Pops This is internet explorer 11 (11.0.9600.18792). So it should be supported?

Comment: @dwirony Bugs are common in Internet Explorer. As a former web-developer myself I can tell you that we don't like fixing IE bugs. Have you thought about switching to Chrome or Edge?

Comment: Now you know why no one uses IE...